# jQuery Countdown timer Showing 0

Tags: jquery, html, countdown

I am playing with jQuery and am stuck at a Countdown timer. So far it was working well. But when I am running the Website, it's showing all the time as 0.

Here is my Code:

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date('03/15/2016 10:00:00 PM');
var remaining = end - now;
var countTo = remaining.valueOf();    
//    var countTo = 25 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 + now.valueOf();    
alert(countTo);

$('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
    $(this).find('.days').text(event.offset.totalDays);
    $(this).find('.hours').text(event.offset.hours);
    $(this).find('.minutes').text(event.offset.minutes);
    $(this).find('.seconds').text(event.offset.seconds);
});
```

When I use the commented **countTo**, the whole thing works. And as both **countTo** returns TimeStamp, I am not understanding why it is not working. Any help will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: create a fiddle of it.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, Please have a look here: https://jsfiddle.net/Sourov00/6ey2xhne/1/

Comment: Fiddle is not working, you forgot to add external resources with example like jQuery, countdown js etc.

Comment: @KundanSinghChouhan, I have updated the Fiddle. Please have a look.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution myself after waiting for others. Adding **now** with the **remaining** did the trick for me.

```
var now = new Date();
var end = new Date('03/15/2016 10:00:00 PM');
var remaining = end - now;
var countTo = remaining.valueOf() + now.valueOf();    
alert(remaining);

$('.timer').countdown(countTo, function(event) {
    $(this).find('.days').text(event.offset.totalDays);
    $(this).find('.hours').text(event.offset.hours);
    $(this).find('.minutes').text(event.offset.minutes);
    $(this).find('.seconds').text(event.offset.seconds);
});
```

Thanks.